# Is there a way to create declarations using generics in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, macros

I have been implementing a kind of observer pattern in c#, that goes like this:

```
public delegate void MyEventOccurred(MyEventArg arg);
public interface IMyEventOccurred
{
    void OnMyEventOccurred(MyEventArg arg);
}

class MyProviderClass
{
    protected MyEventOccurred OnMyEventOccurredHandler;
    public void AddMyEventOccurredHandler(MyEventOccurred handler)
    {
        OnMyEventOccurredHandler -= handler;
        OnMyEventOccurredHandler += handler;
    }

    public void RemoveMyEventOccurredHandler(MyEventOccurred handler)
    {
        OnMyEventOcurredHandler -= handler;
    } 
}
```

To use this class we have the following:

```
class MyObserverClass : IMyEventOccurred
{
    void OnMyEventOccurred(MyEventArg arg)
    {
        // Handle my event
    }

    void StartObserving(MyProviderClass provider)
    {
        provider.AddMyEventOccurredHandler(OnMyEventOccurred);
    }

    void StopObserving(MyProviderClass provider)
    {
        provider.RemoveMyEventOccurredHandler(OnMyEventOccurred);
    }
}
```

I'd be interested in peoples comments on whether there are improvements / better ways to do implement / expose this pattern, however my primary question is about whether there is a way to do all these declarations in a generic way, equivalent to a macro I might have created in C++.

There's a lot of code in declaring this which is completely generic, especially the naming.

In C++ I might use a macro to declare the delegate and the interface, something like:

```
#define DECLARE_EVENT(eventName, eventArg) \
    public delegate void eventName(eventArg arg); \
    public interface I ## eventName \
    { \
        void On ## eventName(eventArg arg); \
    }
```

It's clear that this hides a lot of what's going on, but it does allow quicker implementation, reduces errors and enforces consistency.

Is there some equivalent way of simplifying the implementation in C#?

Thanks

Jules

Comment: Yup, The observable pattern is build into c# and exposed thought events. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx you don't really need to implement the event from scratch, just use the one the language offers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# hasn't code generation ability. You can try realize similar behavior with help site library like a [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net). And i advise use for realization observer-subscriber pattern available interfaces IObserver<T> and IObservable<T> ant took a look on [Reactive Extensions library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use T4 to generate delegate and interface automatically from a list and automatically generate it on build in a similar fashion to C macros.